# Join list of string in python with string %s replacement

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I have a list of ints that I want to join into a string

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

that looks like 'Id = 1 or Id = 2 or Id = 3 or Id = 4 or ID = 5'

I have an answer now but I thought it may be good to get the panel's opinion

**Edit: More information to the nay sayers...**
This not generating SQL directly, this is dynamic expression that is being sent to a Ado.net data services layer that uses Entity Framework underneath. The IN clause which is what is preferred is currently not supported by the dynamic expression handler/EF4 adapter in the service yet and I have to resort to multiple equals statements for the time being.

Comment: Just on the off chance you're trying to do what I think you're doing, you can say `id in ids` in python. It returns true if `id` appears in the list `ids`.

Comment: -1: About the only use for this is generating dynamic SQL.  A very, very bad thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
" or ".join("id = %d" % id for id in ids)
```

Comment: on my machine, replacing the old style formatting with new style drops it from 14usec to 9.3usec. Of course it's still not as good as 7.34 usecs that you get by avoiding string formatting ;)

Comment: @arron - please could you elaborate

Comment: He's talking about `"id = %d" % id` vs. `"id = {}".format(id)` (old vs. new).

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = 'id =' + 'or id ='.join(str(i) for i in ids)
```

If you want to generate dynamic sql as those in the comments have pointed out (don't know how I missed it), you should be doing this as

```
mystring = ' or '.join(['id = ?']*len(ids))
```

where `?` is meant to be replaced with the appropriate escape sequence for your database library. For sqlite3, that's `?`. for MySQLdb, it uses the printf codes, IIRC. You can then pass the list of id's to the cursor as the second argument (usually) after the sql string and it will put them in there in a secure way. This is always the right thing.

Comment: Thank you, the its not dynamic in the standard sense, rather is a predicate expression that is being sent to a ADO.NET Data Services (EF4 ORM underneath) service.